# Slow SQL Query with Sub Query with Order By

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sqlperformance

Here's the query:

```
SELECT product.catalog_product_id AS catalog_id, listing.id AS listing_id, 
    product.size AS size, 0 AS amount, 
    listing.list_price AS price, 
    listing.created_at AS created_date 
FROM product
INNER JOIN listing ON listing.product_id = product.id 
WHERE product.catalog_product_id = XXXX
    AND listing.id = (
        SELECT l.id
        FROM listing l
        INNER JOIN product i ON l.product_id = i.id
        WHERE i.size = product.size AND i.catalog_product_id = XXXX
        ORDER BY l.list_price ASC, l.created_at ASC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Sub Query is this get listing ID for lowest price. Sub Query is slowing down with Order by. I have already created indexes and it still takes 5-6 seconds.

Table Structure:

catalog: This is master products catalog table

```
Catalog
-------
id
sku
name
description
```

products : Stores product variant(size options)

```
Products
--------
id
catalog_id
size
```

listing table:: stores product listing, One Product size option can have multiple product listings with different prices.

```
listing
---------
id
product_id
list_price
created_at
```

Output:
http://prntscr.com/kqh7fg

It shows lowest price for each listing and size.

Comment: I'm a bit thrown off by your repeating the same join, between the same two tables, in both the outer query and subquery.  Could you include some sample data which shows what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Sure, Let me add some sample data here.

Comment: Pls also include the output of the explain

Comment: updated table structure and output screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort out this.

```
SELECT product.catalog_product_id AS catalog_id, listing.id AS listing_id, 
product.size AS size,
listing.list_price AS price, 
listing.created_at AS created_date
FROM product
INNER JOIN listing ON listing.product_id = product.id
AND product.catalog_product_id = XXXX 
AND listing.id IN 
(
SELECT MIN(l.id)
FROM listing l
INNER JOIN product i ON l.product_id = i.id
WHERE i.catalog_product_id = XXXX 
AND list_price = (
SELECT MIN(list_price)
FROM listing l
INNER JOIN product it ON l.product_id = it.id
WHERE it.catalog_product_id = XXXX AND it.size = i.size
)
GROUP BY i.size
)
```

Instead of using:

```
ORDER BY l.list_price ASC, l.created_at ASC  LIMIT 1
```

I have used Min(Price) and Group By Size to get min price listing.

Query Performance improved from 5 sec to .5 seconds

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your subquery doesn't really do anything, try this. If this doesn't work, post the output of the explain statement and avoid using table aliases like 'l' and 'i'. It's really hard to read and the chances of mistakes increase a lot (for example, you joined the 'product.size' on itself for some reason).

```
SELECT
            product.catalog_product_id AS catalog_id,
            listing.id AS listing_id, 
            product.size AS size, 0 AS amount, 
            listing.list_price AS price, 
            listing.created_at AS created_date 
FROM        product
INNER JOIN  listing
    ON      listing.product_id = product.id 
WHERE       product.catalog_product_id = ?
ORDER BY    listing.list_price ASC,
            listing.created_at ASC
LIMIT       1
```